# JQuery validate with multiple custome methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to create a validation for a couple elements. The miminum test I'm trying is something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input id="valCategories" class="valCategories" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input id="valPermissions" class="valPermissions" type="hidden" value="0" />

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 // jQuery Validate Settings
 $.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: ''
 });
 $.validator.addClassRules({});
 
 $.validator.addMethod('valPermissions', function (value, element) {
     return !!+value;
 },"error permissions");
 $.validator.addMethod('valCategories', function (value, element) {
     return !!+value;
 },"error categories");

 $('form').validate();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting to get two error messages:
- error permissions
- error categories
but no matter what I try I only get a single error message.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You previous error message is getting overriden .

Comment: That's not the problem @DipakThoke. The comments provided later add some valid options but the real problem was that my inputs were missing the "name" attribute.

Comment: The length of the accepted answer is ridiculous considering that the only issue is the missing `name` attributes, and FWIW, you do not need the `.addClassRules()` method in your case.  http://jsfiddle.net/wk8v1bj7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are thinking in somewhat wrong direction and trying to use jquery validate plugin in incorrect way. The correct way to use custom method for multiple field is as follows. Basically you need to define custom method first and then you need to bind them to respective form fields. Also you can attach same method to multiple fields too if you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // jQuery Validate Settings
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ''
  });
  $.validator.addClassRules({});


  $.validator.addMethod('valCategoriesMeth', function(value, element) {
    return !!+value;
  }, "error categories");

  $.validator.addMethod('valPermissionsMeth', function(value, element) {
    return !!+value;
  }, "error permissions");



  $('form').validate({
    rules: {
      valCategories: {
        // Add the custom validation methods to the valCategories input
        valCategoriesMeth: true
      },
      valPermissions: {
        // Add the custom validation methods to the valPermissions input
        valPermissionsMeth: true
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <input id="valCategories" name="valCategories" class="valCategories" type="hidden" value="0" />

    <input id="valPermissions" name="valPermissions" class="valPermissions" type="hidden" value="0" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

With `addClassRules` approach you can do it in following way:

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' });
  
$(document).ready(function() {

  // jQuery Validate Settings
  

  $.validator.addMethod('valCategoriesMeth', function(value, element) {
    return !!+value;
  }, "error categories");

  $.validator.addMethod('valPermissionsMeth', function(value, element) {
    return !!+value;
  }, "error permissions");

  $.validator.addClassRules({
    valCategories: {
      valCategoriesMeth: true
    },
    valPermissions: {
      valPermissionsMeth: true
    }
  });

  $('form').validate();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>

    <input id="valCategories"  name="valCategories" class="valCategories" type="hidden" value="0" />
   
   <input id="valPermissions" name="valPermissions" class="valPermissions" type="hidden" value="0" />
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: I tried your changes and it worked, but I don't quite understand why my option was not correct. I was under the impression that on my version the methods were binded by the class name on the input. Is that not the case?

Comment: no. its not like that. we need to specify the `rules` to invoke those custom methods. I guess you are mixing the logic with `addClassRules` method of validate plugin. that is somewhat different but can be used here in your example.

Comment: So you mean that you cannot link the custom methods using classes? For example I'm using the "required" class for normal required fields, and initially I was using the class "valCategories" to force any fields that had that class to validate using the custom method. Using your approach I need to define a rule for each input. I was expecting to be able to do the same thing using the class name.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Seems to work fine now. I just noticed though that my initial code will work IF I add a name to both inputs. So seems I was not that wrong after all!

Comment: The length of this answer is ridiculous considering the only thing breaking the plugin was the OP's failure to put `name` attributes on the `input` elements.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/wk8v1bj7/